# where can I find the list of allowable props or attributes for each component supported by styled-components

Tags: reactjs, components, styled-components, react-props

Starting our in react, it is easy to find tutorials that show how to start with react and styled components.  I find it is easy, but it is hard to get the styling I want because I cannot find a dictionary equivalent that shows the allowable list of styled-components with a internal list of the allowable attributes or values.

For instance (only) the *button* component is very common, but none of the documentation shows the allowable values of say the *type* attribute. how would you know that the *type* attribute exists, and then know that there are only three allowable values *button|onsubmit|reset*.

Can anyone point me to a useful dictionary or cheatsheet for styled-components as used with React.

It seems you cannot find options through a typescript autocomplete method in vs code.

I realise that styled-components is a very useful layer over javascript over html and css, but is there a relevant and complete dictionary of allowed values and components - it does not seem to exist in styled-components documentation.

The lack of a reference doc for styled-component values makes it hard for me as a new starter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While [`styled-components`](https://www.styled-components.com/docs) wraps CSS code it has no predefined components.

> Utilising tagged template literals (a recent addition to JavaScript) and the power of CSS, styled-components allows you to write actual CSS code to style your components. It also removes the mapping between components and styles – using components as a low-level styling construct could not be easier!

Refer to [MDN HTML elements reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element) for the list off all HTML elements and their properties.

Also, if you styling a custom component, you should be aware of its properties within the corresponding documentation (if the component from a library), or use [`PropTypes`](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html), [`Flow`](https://flow.org/) or [`TypeScript`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/).